# Server structure for webapp + db + memcached

Tags: vps

I've been checking around but I still have doubts on how to proceed, that's why I'm adding this question.

I want to deploy a number of small (very low usage) apps written in Play Framework to my servers. The stack would be: nginx + play framework servers (one epr app) + mysql + memcached

Although each application has low usage, there are several of them (so the usage piles up) and the idea is to add many more in the few next months.

Memcache should not store too many objects, as the content users see is not personalized in most cases (so a few objects would serve many many users)

What would you recommend and why:
- Everything in one vps box
- 1 vps box for nginx + play servers + mysql and another (smaller) for memcache
- 1 box for nginx + play, 1 for mysql and 1 for memcache
- Another

As a note, optimizing the budget is relevant but I do't have any problem on spending extra bucks in one (relatively cheap) extra box if the gains are significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on exactly how "low usage" your low usage apps will be, how much resources each app will take up when quiescent, and how big a box you want to get.

I'd be inclined to start with everything in one box, but make sure everything is properly loosely coupled to allow easy separation of services (service CNAMEs for everything, that sort of thing) when/if demand picks up or you realise you underestimated how much resources things would need.